# Digital Multimeter "Continuity test" only one single beep

Tags: multimeter, continuity

Well I have two electronic circuit, one is broken and the other is solid and working. While I am making Continuity test with Fluke Multimeter on working electronic circuit, the bip voice heared only once time. but broken part is giving continutiy bip voice. How can a digital multimeter give only once bip voice. what does it mean.

Comment: You did remember to disconnect the system being tested from all power sources, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A short burst of beeping from a continuity tester generally means that there is momentary current flow in the circuit from the tester until some capacitance gets charged up and the current flow stops.

On the other hand the continuous tone indicates an actual short and the current from the tester flows as long as the probes are attached to the circuit under test.

So if you are seeing your "bad unit" show the continuous beeping it probably means that there is a short circuit.

Comment: well there are lots of smd capacitance on circuit. how can I find easly the short circuit capacitance? do you have any tips?

Comment: Easiest Way: Use a capacitance measurement meter.

Answer (score 2):

A charging capacitance appears as a short and then an open when fully charged.